Can everything ever go back to normal when an employee decides to stay after they talked with their boss?
I have heard many stories from my friends who decide to leave a company, and the company promises to match whatever the new job's offering. So far I didn't hear anyone accepting to stay.
Let's say Greg is leaving Alpha Inc. for a 10% higher salary and more vacation days in Beta Inc.
There are two main reasons that I've heard why Greg would reject Alpha Inc. even if they match the offer.

If Greg decides to stay, it's now been clear that he was looking for some other career option. After his essential contributions to whatever he's working on, Alpha Inc. simply can let him go.
If the company was able to pay that much for his efforts, why did they wait for him to tell he's quitting? What if he again becomes an underpaid employee in the future?

My question is for the first reason. If there is an occasion that you know where an employee who decided to leave, gives up his decision and stays, what is the correct way of handling the uncomfortable situation of the superior knowing his employee was at job hunting? Does that hurt the employee's career chances in their current company?
If you're a manager, wouldn't you feel a bit off knowing that your colleague will leave as soon as they find a better offer that you cannot match?

"is there any occasion that you know of" it's not a useful question. The answer, especially when asked on a global discussion, is always going to be yes; there will be an instance, somewhere, where things that worked out that way or where the side effects have not yet become visible. Even asking for frequency is not a useful question, since none of us has all the data. I'm afraid I have to vote to close this one as unanswerable as written.

@keshlam I've edited the question and now it's not a yes-no question

"wouldn't you feel" is still an opinion question, which is also a reason for closure. I'm afraid what you are trying to ask, at least in its current form, is simply not a good fit for Stack Exchange. We will see if others agree with me; that's why close and reopen are voting processes.

@keshlam I think you are being prejudicial because of my lack of activity in this site. The third most voted question literally asks I feel like I'm being criticized for doing my assigned task too well. But am I being unfair here?

In most cases, people leave a manager, not the compensation. The only case I know where it worked out was when the worker got moved to another department. Otherwise, the team trust has been broken.

I didn't even look at who you were or how much activity you have. I am just reacting to the question as posed. I may be wrong. The community will decide.


If there is an occasion that you know where an employee who decided to leave, gives up his decision and stays, what is the correct way of handling the uncomfortable situation of the superior knowing his employee was at job hunting? Does that hurt the employee's career chances in their current company?

If you've just paid to retain the employee, it would be a very strange form of self-harm to then hobble their career, which will once again create the impetus to leave that you've just shelled out to neutralise.
I would suggest the situation is only uncomfortable if the employee suggested that their reasons for wanting to leave was a personal difference - in which case, the only typical case why they might stay longer is because you've absolutely stuffed their mouths with gold. More typically, employees will even take a modest pay cut to be away from a toxic environment.
If they were leaving just for money or progression which they didn't think you'd give, then why should there be ongoing discomfort on your part when you offer to meet this and they accept?

If you're a manager, wouldn't you feel a bit off knowing that your colleague will leave as soon as they find a better offer that you cannot match?

Why should there be such a better offer, unless you are not paying the market rate in the first place?
Unless you're dissatisfied with performance and want the employee to leave, then for an existing employee with accumulated experience, you should almost always be able to outdo whatever any other employer is willing to offer, simply because the employee is already a known quantity to you who are habituated to their particular role in your particular firm.
The only exception is when the market is structured in a way where your firm a bottom-feeder, or certainly lower in the chain than a much more powerful employer. But then you cannot match these offers and would have to let them go. In which case you cannot expect employees not to accept better offers from better employers - you simply have to sustain the loss when it occurs - and you wouldn't be in the position of feeling uncomfortable because they'd be gone!
The only situation I can vaguely conceive where there would be discomfort, would be if you knew you were shafting them all along, and yet despite this past cynicism you are now shamed that they know you were shafting them, and you feel uneasy at the loss of trust. Unfortunately the only answer to this is to try and avoid the situation in the first place, or make sure you do better going forward.

@JoeStrazzere, if there was always a better offer elsewhere for all of your employees, then why would anyone ever stay, and in what sense is your own rate that of the market?

@JoeStrazzere, and they leave for reasons other than money too, and an "offer" does not necessarily just consist of comparing the wage. But I'd still like to understand more about your thinking. I've left jobs for better pay many times, and they really were better offers. I've only once left the better job later for non-financial reasons, and that was because poor conditions continued to an unacceptable degree (but it wasn't worse than the predecessor).

@JoeStrazzere, the thing I'm not following about your thinking is how "always a better offer" reconciles with the current employer "paying market rate". I got better offers because I wasn't being paid market rate by my existing employer at the time.

People have many reasons to stay besides money, or even more interesting work, or better opportunities to learn and contribute. Each person has to "make their own bed", as the saying goes. But anything negative in the workplace is a possible impetus to leave. I might tacitly agree to accept 'less', but not discomfort or abuse.

It depends is the real answer.
There is a trust that a manager has in their team members. This trust isn't binary. The trust and the intrinsic need to remove as much uncertainty as possible tends to drive many managers.
Ego, unfortunatly, drives some. These managers now have a bruised ego.
If an employee is looking elsewhere, there is reason. If the job search got to the point of saying that "I am leaving", it is almost always more than about money.
If the reason was strictly money, the manager and company are out of touch anyway. There is a lack of communication and understanding of the salary market.
If the reason is something fixable and both sides want to give it a try, then there is a shot to make it work.
Assuming the employee stays, it can't be understated that it will be a while before the managers can really trust them.

@JoeStrazzere, I think you underestimate how hard-faced some employers are. It's true that being hard-faced with wages is often accompanied by other problems, including poor culture, vicious management, and "dead sea"-style incompetence from many others, but the root of all these is the adversarial wage policy, because better people leave all the time, whilst the less competent and easily frightened stay and grow resentful. (1/2)

You end up with a management layer (mal-)adapted to this conflict too whose attitudes grow weary, hostile, and bitter, and whose subordinates constantly churn, whilst good managers seek better employment where they can shine and enjoy a positive culture and relatively stable relationships. (2/2)

@JoeStrazzere, I understand your constraints as a middle manager, but the budgets you are assigned are choices, not natural laws. You don't seem to acknowledge the possibility that you have simply been set a budget which isn't set at the market rate, but is a putch by senior management to attack the retained workforce and to try and undercut the market rate. If your wage budget is always positioned like that, there will forever be other employers paying more than you, which is exactly what you say you have observed. You don't seem to have ruled out, or even considered, this explanation.

The "department/company budget" was not handed to Moses on stone tablets. It was set by fallible humans with conflicting priorities. If those fallible humans prioritize short-term profitability over medium-/long-term staff development & retention then middle-managers in this company are always going to be stuck in the position of disappointing their reports with below market-average pay - and facing the consequences of that choice handed down to them. An even with the budget being "set" there are always exceptions if middle managers are able to mount a convincing case to their superiors ...

Some companies have a "people are fungible mindset". In a meta way, they are. But that darn sure either doesn't take into account the disruption. Fully onboarding a new person / knowledge loss or lack of management acumen of why it matters. The phrase "you have to retain them to train them" somes it up.

Some time ago there was a question here where someone had a better offer, took a better counter offer from the old company, accepted it and rejected the new offer, then got fired the next day.
With decent, normal people everything would be fine. Not all people fall into that category.
Now in this question you state it’s uncomfortable knowing that the employee was looking for another job? Why? It’s perfectly normal behaviour. If they came back for example because of sn improved salary, that means they were underpaid for a long time.

Someone once said, "pay people enough to take money off the table". But often there is only so much money on the table to work with. I'm trying to imagine planning to leave and then deciding to stay. But then being fired the next day feels like something that would move me to fury.
